# Get Notified after 1st rotation of Text in Text View(ellipsize="marquee") in Android

Tags: android, android-custom-view, textview

**What I have:** I have a TextView with Ellipsize = Marquee. The textview's focus is true, so that I don't have to focus it manually, to start the text rotation.

**What I want:** I want to do some operation when the 1st rotation of the text is complete. e.g. I want to show a toast or change the text of the textview. Is there anything like an event is raised after the rotation, before starting the 2nd cycle of text rotation.

**What is the problem:** I cant figure out on how to get notified when the first rotation of the text in TextView is complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a custom marquee and when that marquee ends I can get a notification.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6704080/how-to-reverse-the-direction-of-marquee-of-a-textview), I have answered my own question before this one, as these two question were related.