# textView scroll text

Tags: android, textview

I want to create a textView. I did that.

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/TxttopTitle"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:lines="1"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:text="البحث البحثالبحثالبحثالبحثالبحثالبحثالبحثالبحثالبحثالبحثالبحثالبحث" />
```

The problem is:
I want that the text scroll from right to left (insteed of left to right)

Can i do that?

Comment: You may have to write a method to do this yourself: [How to reverse the direction of marquee of a TextView](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6704080/1267661)

Comment: instead if lines="1" try adding android:singleLine="true"