# Android marquee of arabic

Tags: android, arabic, marquee

I have writing some code of marquee in textview.

When I change the language from English to Arabic.

The text's direction will change from right to left(original is left to right in English), but the marquee's direction don't change, it always scroll from right to left.

My code as below

`<TextView
     android:id="@+id/label"
     android:layout_width="@dimen/menu_item_txt_width"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
     android:gravity="center_horizontal"
     android:text="@string/empty"
     android:textColor="@drawable/menu_txt_color"
     android:textSize="@dimen/menu_item_txt_size"
     android:ellipsize="marquee"
     android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever" 
     android:scrollHorizontally="true"
     android:singleLine="true"
     />`

Can anyone provide me simple way to fix it?

In the English the text direction is "Move to[ 888888888 ]" ---> left to right
In the Arabic the text direction is "[ 888888888 ]نقل الى" right to left

But in the marquee,

In English version, when I not focus the textview, it will show "Move to[ 88", then I focus it will scroll and show "88888 ]"       -----> right to left

In Arabic version, when I not focus the textview, it will show "88 ]نقل الى", then I focus it will scroll and show "نقل     "       ----->  right to left

Comment: what you want to do actully?

Comment: @rajshree I think the OP wants marquee effect from right to left.

Comment: Use this may its helps :)


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6704080/how-to-reverse-the-direction-of-marquee-of-a-textview

Comment: you need to check the language direction, if it is right to left, then you need to change the direction dynamically to RTL

Comment: @rajshree I had update the question, I want to marquee effect from left to right in Arabic language.

Comment: @waqaslam I want marquee effect from left to right in Arabic language

Comment: @Ammaraly I had try these solution in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6704080/how-to-reverse-the-direction-of-marquee-of-a-textview but some cannot get effect and some are difficult

Comment: @KhalidTaha I will check the language in the future. But I need change marquee's direction can work. I had try android:textDirection, but it didn't get the effect.

Answer (score -1):

There's no native way of achieving that, i.e., there's not a built-in method that will do what you want, but there's a workaround to make it work that way. Wrap your `TextView` into a `HorizontalScrollView` and you'll need to control it with the position of the scrollbar. Firstly, get the scrollbar position with this:

```
scrollPos = (int) tv.getLayout().getLineWidth(0);
```

The next step is to define a `Handler` and call recursively until you reach the scroll limit, this should work:

```
Handler hsHandler = new Handler() {
  @Override
  public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    // Being hsView your HorizontalScrollView
    hsView.scrollTo(scrollPos, 0);
    scrollPos--;
    if (scrollPos >= 0)
      hsHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
  }
};
```

Comment: there should be an comment not answer that you copy paste

Comment: That's not a copy and paste, that's a solution I've used in one of my projects years ago and it still works. I actually copied that from my project.

Comment: Dear nKn,
Thanks your reply, I have try this code in the past, but I always get NullPointerException in tv.getLayout().

   <HorizontalScrollView
       android:id="@+id/hsview"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     <TextView
           android:id="@+id/label"
                  ...
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever" 
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            />
        </HorizontalScrollView>

Comment: @user3374004 You're probably calling it too early, have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16558948/how-to-use-textview-getlayout-it-returns-null

Comment: @nKn I had try this, and it could't occur exception, but it cannot work. Are width and height incorrect?