# How to show full text in single line

Tags: android, animation, textview, marquee

I want to show full text in single line,I have tried for marquee but it's for right to left,I want to scroll text from left to right,tried all possible options finally ended with solution of Animation but in animation it animates total view & textview showing ... for long text. Please help me.. thnks in advance..!!

Comment: marque from left to right: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6704080/how-to-reverse-the-direction-of-marquee-of-a-textview

Comment: not clear with this answer !!

Comment: Check this "I have tried for marquee but it's for right to left,I want to scroll text from left to right," from your question. My answer for scroll marque from left to right

Comment: @Lokesh Thank u bt m not clear with that link coz there only handler is created bt not explained how to use or from where to call that.

Comment: Why cant you try with webview with custom height and width. Link has one more answer with webview with html tag and added direction property

Answer (score 2):

Place your TextView under horizontal scroll view.

Comment: after placing? wht is next?

Answer (score 1):

Another simple way is using HTML and also you can change direction easily `direction="Left"`

```
<html><body><FONT COLOR="#000000" ><marquee id="mrqSlogan"  direction="Left" style="width: auto;" >text your</marquee></FONT></body></html>
```

And Pass to **WebView**

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, yourhtmltext, "text/html" , null, null);
```

Comment: Thank u lokesh but i want to ratate only & only if the text size is bigger.

Answer (score 0):

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/editText1" 
android:layout_width="210dp" 
android:layout_height="40dp" 
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
android:layout_centerVertical="true" 
android:ems="10" 
android:maxLines="1" 
android:maxLength="10" 
android:padding="5dp" 
android:paddingBottom="5dp" 
android:paddingEnd="0dp" 
android:paddingLeft="0dp" 
android:paddingRight="5dp" 
android:paddingStart="5dp" 
android:paddingTop="5dp" 
android:textColor="#0A0C0D">
<requestFocus/>
 </EditText>
```