# marquee textview left to right

Tags: android

I'm using this textview and it works fine. but current marquee is right to left. I want to change it from left to right . how can I change it ?

```
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_view_clerk"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                android:text="سنکیبنسکین مسنبک سنیکبم نککسن  کمن کمینسبکم نکن کنسبک سکیم بنکسمنیب کمسنی ب"
                android:lines="1"
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
                android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
                android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:freezesText="true"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/img_view_clerk"/>
```

Comment: Check out this repository: [CustomViews](https://github.com/activesince93/CustomViews). Use `ScrollingTextView` for marquee effect.

Comment: Arabic font  android will make it itself...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reverse the direction of marquee of a TextView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6704080/how-to-reverse-the-direction-of-marquee-of-a-textview)

Answer (score 2):

You can better use animation for that.

```
Animation animationToRight = new TranslateAnimation(-400,400, 0, 0);
    Animation animationToLeft = new TranslateAnimation(400, -400, 0, 0);

animationToLeft.setDuration(12000); 
    animationToLeft.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);
    animationToLeft.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
TextView textView= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewMarqToRight);

    textViewMarqToLeft.setAnimation(animationToLeft);
```

You can chose any one animation and appply it to your desired view.

Answer (score 2):

Use below xml code in new folder under res :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:fillAfter="true">

   <translate
        android:fromXDelta="-3%p"
        android:toXDelta="3%p"
        android:duration="1200" />
</set>
```

And, just add this to your textview :

```
yourTextView.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(activity, R.newfolder.move));
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out `BidiFormatter`, added recently in the Compatibility Package and [native rtl support](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2013/03/native-rtl-support-in-android-42.html) blog

You can then set the marquee programmatically as following

```
if (bidiFormatter.isRtlContext()) {
   txt_view_clerk.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.BEGIN);
} else {
   txt_view_clerk.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
}
```

Alternatively you can try

`android:textDirection="anyRtl"` in you xml.